# What happens when I use https?

Tags: http, https

In terms of what's happening between the client and server, what happens when I use `https` instead of `http`? What exactly makes it more secure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTTPS uses SSL to encrypt communication between the server and the client. In short, SSL works by installing a certificate on the client. This certificate is verified by the server, and embedded in the certificate is an encryption key which is used to encrypt the communication between the server and the client.

See [this](http://www.verisign.com/ssl/ssl-information-center/how-ssl-security-works/) article for details on how SSL works.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

over http the request parameters are sent as plain text.  You can view this, for example when you open firebug in Firefox, or console in Chrome and view headers.

over https, the request is encrypted so that a 3rd party "sniffing" or listening/watching/recording traffic in between client and server cannot easily decode the message.